# Incluindo Intervalo de Confiança em uma Linha de uma Matriz

Tags: r, latex

Quero criar uma matriz de 38 linhas e duas colunas com coeficientes nas linhas ímpares e os intervalos de confiança para os parâmetros nas linhas pares.

Em seguida chamar o *stargazer*.

Meu código é:

```
library(quantreg)

y <- rnorm(200)
x <- matrix(rnorm(123),200)
fit <- rq(y~x,tau=seq(0.05, 0.95, by = 0.05),method="br")

summary(fit,se="nid")
```

Consegui avançar até aqui:

Repare que consigo colocar os coeficientes nas linhas ímpares sem problemas. O erro óbvio está quando tento construir e colocar o intervalo de confiança dos parâmetros nas linhas pares:

```
fit_Matrix<-matrix(0,38,2)

for(i in 1:19) for (j in seq(1, 38, by = 2)[i]) for (k in seq(2, 38, by = 2)[i]) { 

fit_Matrix[j,1]<-summary(fit,se="nid")[[i]]$coefficients[1]
fit_Matrix[j,2]<-summary(fit,se="nid")[[i]]$coefficients[2]

fit_Matrix[k,1]<-summary(fit,se="nid")[[i]]$coefficients[1]-1.645*summary(fit,se="nid")[[i]]$coefficients[3]; 
summary(fit,se="nid")[[i]]$coefficients[1]+1.645*summary(fit,se="nid")[[i]]$coefficients[3]

fit_Matrix[k,2]<-summary(fit,se="nid")[[i]]$coefficients[2]-1.645*summary(fit,se="nid")[[1]]$coefficients[4];
summary(fit,se="nid")[[i]]$coefficients[2]-1.645*summary(fit,se="nid")[[i]]$coefficients[4]

}
```

A segunda parte do código está errada. Como faço para corrigir?
Lembrando que gostaria de transporta a matriz para o LaTeX.

Obrigado, desde já.

Comment: A tua regressão tem dois parâmetros. Assim, imagino que as linhas ímpares da fit_Matrix possuem dois números: na coluna 1 vai o intercepto e na coluna 2 vai o coeficiente angular. Mas como colocar os intervalos de confiança, que são compostos por dois números para cada parâmetro, em apenas uma linha da matriz? Tu quer o IC de um parâmetro apenas ou a tua fit_Matrix vai ter que ter 4 elementos por linha par?

Comment: Tem como eu fazer com 4 elementos por linha par? Teria como colocar os dois numeros do intervalo juntos em cada linha par?

Comment: Tem como fazer. Mas o teu código tem um problema: o objeto fit não tem 19 elementos como deveria. Para mim só aparecem 14. Faz um length(fit) e confere isto. Depois, edita o post original para que o teu código seja, de fato, reproduzível.

Comment: Obrigado! Relamente o `lenght` é 14. Mas a informação que eu quero esta no `summary` que possui 19. Não é? Pelo que vi 14 é o tamanho da lista: `str(fit)`.

Comment: Eu que peço desculpas. Tinha entendido errado um detalhe do teu resultado. O length está correto.

Answer (score 0):

Segue a minha sugestão de resposta. Meu código ficou meio porco, lento e feio, mas estou com um pouco de pressa.

```
library(quantreg)

y   <- rnorm(200)
x   <- matrix(rnorm(123), 200)
fit <- rq(y~x, tau=seq(0.05, 0.95, by = 0.05), method="br")

summary(fit, se="nid")

fit_Matrix <- matrix(NA, 38, 4)
index.coef <- seq(1, 37, 2)
index.ic   <- seq(2, 38, 2)

fit_Matrix[index.coef, 1] <- fit$coefficients[1, ]
fit_Matrix[index.coef, 3] <- fit$coefficients[2, ]

mult <- 1.645
i    <- 1

for (j in index.ic){

  fit_Matrix[j, 1] <- unlist(summary(fit, se="nid")[[i]][3][1])[1] - mult*unlist(summary(fit, se="nid")[[i]][3][1])[3]
  fit_Matrix[j, 2] <- unlist(summary(fit, se="nid")[[i]][3][1])[1] + mult*unlist(summary(fit, se="nid")[[i]][3][1])[3]
  fit_Matrix[j, 3] <- unlist(summary(fit, se="nid")[[i]][3][1])[2] - mult*unlist(summary(fit, se="nid")[[i]][3][1])[4]
  fit_Matrix[j, 4] <- unlist(summary(fit, se="nid")[[i]][3][1])[2] + mult*unlist(summary(fit, se="nid")[[i]][3][1])[4]

  i <- i+1

}

fit_Matrix
```

Não consegui conferir as contas, mas acho que estão todas certas.

Comment: Valeu! Ajudou demais!